# Multiple UIWebViews javaScript performance?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit

I have two UIWebViews.

1 of them runs JavaScript Code.

On the same time I try to scroll the second one, and there some gliches in the scroll (Sometimes it even stuck for 1 second!).

Is there a solution for this problem? Why does it happen?

Thanks!